# How to make a mongodb query with nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo db collection in which each document has two nested arrays (each document has an element that stores an array which stores documents that store another array) and I only want some fields of the deepest document. I have tried different types of projection elements but none of them worked. Right now I am trying the following:

```
let answered_exam = await exams_table.findOne(
{_id: new ObjectId(req.body.course_id)}, 
{projection: { 
  _id: 1, 
  "exams": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$exams",
      "in": { 
        "$this.exam_name": req.body.exam_name,
        "students_exams": {  
          "$map": {
            "input": "$$this.students_exams",
            "in": { "student_email": req.body.student_email },
        }},
      },
    }}
  } 
});
```

The format of an entry in the database is the following:
The block of attributes in the middle are the documents stored in the exams array
(each element is like this). The block from below is the format of the documents.
[image]

Comment: your drawing is the best i have seen, but text JSON is easier, so people can test their queries on them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query1
(unwind)

- you can do a nested map, and filter but here we select 1 exam only
  so data i guess are small, and we can use double unwind for simplicity
- match _id
- unwind `exams`
- match `exam_name`
- unwind `student_exams`
- match `email`
- project to keep only the `professor_notes` and the `mark`
- if you want only 1 result max, add also in the end one more stage
  `{"limit" : 1}`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70220558)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$_id", 1]}}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$exams"}},
  {"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$exams.exam_name", "exam1"]}}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$exams.student_exams"}},
  {"$match": 
    {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$exams.student_exams.student_email", "email1"]}}},
  {"$project": 
    {"_id": 0,
      "professor_notes": "$exams.student_exams.professor_notes",
      "mark": "$exams.student_exams.mark"}}])
```

Query2
(nested map/filters)

- map if not match null else map again doing the same
- on return filter to remove the nulls
- get the first , of the first and replace root

*query is big, it does the same thing, map instead of unwind, and filter instead of match (2 map/2 unwind , 2 filter/2 match)

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70220558-1)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$_id", 1]}}},
  {"$replaceRoot": 
    {"newRoot": 
      {"$arrayElemAt": 
        [{"$arrayElemAt": 
            [{"$filter": 
                {"input": 
                  {"$map": 
                    {"input": "$exams",
                      "in": 
                      {"$cond": 
                        [{"$not": [{"$eq": ["$$exam.exam_name", "exam1"]}]}, null,
                          {"$filter": 
                            {"input": 
                              {"$map": 
                                {"input": "$$exam.student_exams",
                                  "in": 
                                  {"$cond": 
                                    [{"$not": 
                                        [{"$eq": 
                                            ["$$students_exam.student_email", "email1"]}]},
                                      null,
                                      {"professor_notes": 
                                        "$$students_exam.professor_notes",
                                        "mark": "$$students_exam.mark"}]},
                                  "as": "students_exam"}},
                              "cond": {"$ne": ["$$students_exam", null]},
                              "as": "students_exam"}}]},
                      "as": "exam"}},
                  "cond": {"$ne": ["$$exam", null]},
                  "as": "exam"}}, 0]}, 0]}}}])
```

Comment: Why do you use `$expr`? Simply use `{$match: {_id: 1}}` and `{$match: {"exams.exam_name": "exam1"}}`,  `{$match: {"exams.student_exams.student_email": "email1"}}`?

Comment: i didnt wrote those by hand, and in my library is equal complex in code, so i forget sometimes to use the simpler versions.